# MDB starts to consume messages before fully initialization of JNDI names

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, websphere, ibm-mq, message-driven-bean

**AS: Websphere 8.5.5**

**MQ impl: SIB**

During application startup *MDB* starts to invoke **onMessage method**, which in turn invokes **initialContext.lookup** in order *to find specific bean*.
Sometimes (*during variety of startup iterations*) it *returns null instead of reference to bean object*.

This behavior is **nondeterministic**: in some startup iterations bean's context has time for all **JNDI names** initialization due to more longer **MDB initialization** and respectively a pause in message consumption.

Is there any workaround or magic *IBM key* to resolve issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as everyone "love's" Websphere, it was without a doubt an IBM bug. Sorry, i lied.... it was **TWO** bugs at the same time.

- First : 
  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI28099.
  Yep, you need to fix this bug yourself !!!
  Just add this jvm custom property to your server:
  com.ibm.ejs.j2c.J2CServerListener.activateEndpointsOnCRAStarted = true
- Second:
  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM62774
  Yep, this one you need to fix ... drumroll  ... by yourself too !!!
  Just add the second custom property to your server:
  com.ibm.ws.cdi.immediate.ejb.start = true

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways of working around this is by using startup [ordering](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/trun_app_startup.html). Based on the start up order sequence , different deployed applications can be started in sequence. In your case , i would ensure that the EJB component you want is given a lower sequence to start it up first followed by the MDB so that the lookup will never fail

Comment: Thanks for post, but its not allowed to separate MDB as standalone app due to architect preferences. I solved the problem (but i can't guarantee the real reason of this issue), i guess it was non-thread-safe InitialContext. After replacement InitialContext as INSTANCE VARIABLE to static call of InitialContext.doLokup() the problem has gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any additional initialisation happening inside the MDB it is helpful to consider the `@PostContruct` annotation.  I too had the onMessage firing too early, before initialisation was complete, resulting in the message not being processed.  After putting my additional initialisation logic in a method with this annotation, it solved my problem.

```
@PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
....
}
```

Comment: thank for your answer, there where few conditions that didn't allow me to use @Postconstruct (posted my solution)